# Как добавить h заголовки в обозреватель решений MSVS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

1. Почему когда я настраиваю Проект/Свойства/Дополнительные каталоги включаемых файлов, h - файлы из этого каталога не отображаются в обозревателе решений MSVS???
2. Зачем тогда их вручную туда подключать?

Comment: В обозревателе решений отображаются файлы, которые относятся к этому решению. В Дополнительные каталоги включаемых файлов могут указываться папки со сторонними файлами, которые не относятся к этому решению, но нужны для сборки.